# Toggle and re-toggle several <div>-blocks

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website with several blocks, each of them containing six  with different statements like this:

Block A

- A-1
- A-2
- A-3
- A-4
- A-5
- A-6

Block B

- B-1
- B-2
- ...

In every block the user decides to click on one item (e. g. A-3), this item (e. g. A-3) will stay and the five other items will disappear (via .toggle()).

If you click on the selected item (e. g. A-3), all items of a block will become visible again and the user can make his or her choice again.

After every block is reduced to one item (e. g. A-3, B-2, C-4, D-6 ...), I want to get the content of the selected items to collect them into a textarea, a variable or something else.

My actual code looks like this:

```
    "use strict";

$(document).ready(function () {

  sizeContent();

  $(window).resize(sizeContent);

  function sizeContent() {
    var newHeight = ($("html").height() - $(".pageheader").height() - $(".pagefooter").height()) + "px";
    $(".wrap").css("min-height", newHeight);
 }



  $( "div#a.a" ).click( function () {
    $( "div#b.a, div#c.a, div#d.a, div#e.a, div#f.a, h4.headline_a " ).toggle("slow");
  });

  $( "div#b.a" ).click( function () {
    $( "div#a.a, div#c.a, div#d.a, div#e.a, div#f.a, h4.headline_a " ).toggle("slow");
  });

  $( "div#c.a" ).click( function () {
    $( "div#b.a, div#a.a, div#d.a, div#e.a, div#f.a, h4.headline_a " ).toggle("slow");
  });

  $( "div#d.a" ).click( function () {
    $( "div#b.a, div#c.a, div#a.a, div#e.a, div#f.a, h4.headline_a " ).toggle("slow");
  });

  $( "div#e.a" ).click( function () {
    $( "div#b.a, div#c.a, div#d.a, div#a.a, div#f.a, h4.headline_a " ).toggle("slow");
  });

  $( "div#f.a" ).click( function () {
    $( "div#b.a, div#c.a, div#d.a, div#e.a, div#a.a, h4.headline_a " ).toggle("slow");
  });



  $( "div.bemerkung_done" ).click(function () {
      var print = $( "div.div_a" ).text();
      $( "div.bemerkung_done" ).after( print );
  });


});
```

My question is: How can I get the one item that is visible after toggling the rest? I've already tried to change the id with the onclick-function, but then nothing happens because I think, it simply doesn't correspond to the changed id. How can I solve this problem?

I'm looking forward to any suggestion and appreciate your help!

EDIT: My html-code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testseite</title>

    <meta name="description" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Grafiken/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Grafiken/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="bemerkung" id="bemerkung">

<header role="banner" class="pageheader" >

    <div class="inside">
        <a href="index.php" title="home" id="logo">
            <img src="Grafiken/logo.png" alt="home">
        </a>
    </div> <!-- inside -->

</header>

<div class="wrap">
    <main class="main">

        <div class="headline">
            <h3>Ueberschrift</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="div_a">
            <h4 class="headline_a">Block A</h4>
            <div class="a" id="a">
                <p>A-1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="a" id="b">
                <p>A-2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="a" id="c">
                <p>A-3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="a" id="d">
                <p>A-4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="a" id="e">
                <p>A-5</p>
            </div>
            <div class="a" id="f">
                <p>A-6</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bemerkung_done">
            <p class="bemerkung_generieren">>> Bemerkung generieren</p>
        </div>


    </main>
</div>

<footer role="contentinfo" class="pagefooter">
    <div class="inside">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: May you also post the HTML?

Comment: I just edited the code - sorry for missing the html-code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get items which are visible on the page you can use the [:visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Use following code to read the text

```
var print = $( "div.a:visible" ).text();
```

instead of this

```
var print = $( "div.div_a" ).text();
```

Reference : https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Also looking at your code, the way you are toggling each element is not a good. You can do this in a cleaner manner, use Following code to toggle the blocks.

```
$( "div.a" ).click(function(){
$( "div.a" ).not(this).toggle("slow");
})
```

Just change the class for new blocks.

After changing your Javascript code will look something like this(No changes in HTML) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  sizeContent();

  $(window).resize(sizeContent);

  function sizeContent() {
    var newHeight = ($("html").height() - $(".pageheader").height() - $(".pagefooter").height()) + "px";
    $(".wrap").css("min-height", newHeight);
 }


$( "div.a" ).click(function(){
$( "div.a" ).not(this).toggle("slow");
})



  $( "div.bemerkung_done" ).click(function () {
      var print = $( "div.a:visible" ).text();
      $( "div.bemerkung_done" ).after( print );
  });


});
```

Comment: You solved the problem! Thank you very much! I think my thoughts were way too complicated!